# Error with "posts_per_page" = -1 when verify my plugin with WordPress Plugin Coding Standards And Php Codesniffer

Tags: php, wordpress

I am verifying my plugin with wordpress coding standard and php codesniffer but i do not know how to remove this issue:

```
Disabling pagination is prohibited in VIP context, do not set
      |       | `posts_per_page` to `-1` ever.
      |       | (WordPress.VIP.PostsPerPage.posts_per_page)
```

I alway use posts_per_page = -1 to get posts to get all posts, i do not know how to get all posts without this.

Comment: can't you just make the `posts_per_page` a high number? like `999999999`

Comment: They have some notes here  https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/blob/master/WordPress/Tests/VIP/PostsPerPageUnitTest.inc and i don't think the way which set posts_per_page to multiple 9 is a good way :|

Comment: they said it was bad, they didn't say it didn't work.

Comment: Remove the posts_per_page parameter if you're not showing paged results.  The correct way to retrieve all results is to set nopaging to true (nopaging=true).

Comment: @LukePeterson I'm getting this error: "phpcs says Disabling pagination is prohibited in VIP context, do not set `nopaging` to `true` ever." So, apparently, you're not supposed to set `nopaging` to true. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

PHPCS with the WordPress plugin gives this error, for all of the following cases:

```
'nopaging'       => true, // Bad.
'posts_per_page' => 999, // Bad.
'posts_per_page' => -1, // Bad.
```

Why? Basically, if you disable paging, then you could run into serious performance issues if the query has the potential to return more results than your server (or client) could handle.

The rationale seems to be explained in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/issues/83):

> #### No `LIMIT` queries
>
> Using `posts_per_page` (or `numberposts`) with the value set to -1 or an unreasonably high number or setting `nopaging` to `true` opens up the potential for scaling issues if the query ends up querying thousands of posts.
>
> You should always fetch the lowest number possible that still gives you the number of results you find acceptable. Imagine that your site grows over time to include 10,000 posts. If you specify -1 for `posts_per_page`, you’ll query with no limit and fetch all 10,000 posts every time the query runs, which is going to destroy your site’s performance. If you know you’ll never have more than 15 posts, then set posts_per_page to 15. If you think you might have more than 15 that you’d want to display but doubt it’d hit more than 100 ever, set the limit to 100. If it gets much higher than that, you might need to rethink the page architecture a bit.

If you want to stop PHPCS from complaining about this, either fix the code to start using paging, or disable these particular checkes by including this code in your `phpcs.xml` file:

```
<exclude name="WordPress.VIP.PostsPerPage.posts_per_page_nopaging" />
<exclude name="WordPress.VIP.PostsPerPage.posts_per_page_numberposts" />
```

### Update for PHPCS WP version 1.0:

Version 1.0 no longer includes the `WordPress.VIP` policies any more, so you might not see this error if you upgrade it. [See changelog](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/releases/tag/1.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

Just set 'posts_per_page' => PHP_INT_MAX,

That is what I've done and PHPCS is now happy :)